Trouble with ggplot2 in Current Version of R (024.04.2+764)
I am trying to load and use ggplot2 in RStudio. When I try to install, I get the following:
install.packages("ggplot 2")
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘ggplot 2’ is not available for this version of R
A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
According to my packages tab, I have it installed. I updated to the 024.04.2+764 version of R and RStudio within minutes of trying to install. I am running macOS Sonoma 14.5.
Any ideas why I am getting this error?

"ggplot 2" should not have a space.

See "1. You can't spell" in the linked post.
